# Most reliable way to get product page URL that customer added at last in the cart

Tags: cart, redirect, shopping-cart, product-urls

I would like to get the URL of the product which was recently added to cart (lastly added to the cart) and assign it to Continue Shopping url in cart page.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, there  have ***a checkout session variable which is store lastly added to the cart item products id***.

> Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')>getLastAddedProductId()

and using this product id with help `product model`,you can get url easily.

> ```
> $product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
>     ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')>getLastAddedProductId())
>     ->addUrlRewrite();
> $product_collection_url = $product_collection->getFirstItem()->getProductUrl()
> ```

***Here i have product/collection model getting data firster***

Comment: But this gets the last added product ID only once.. I want it to be maintained throughout..